# GitHub commits not verified despite matching GPG Key ID

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

On the command line I generated a new key pair using [the github-api-signature package's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-api-signature) `generateKeyPair` function, providing a name and email of my GitHub account and a random passphrase.

I took the public part of the generated key pair and put it [in my GitHub account on the keys page](https://github.com/settings/keys).

I took the private key and provided it to the snippet of code below.

The request to create the commit returns successfully as does the programmatic creation of the PR, but when I visit the commits page of the PR there is a box saying 'Unverified' with the message "The signature in this commit could not be verified. Someone may be trying to trick you."

[image]

I compared the GPG key ID it provides me on this page with those listed in my GitHub keys page and it matches, so why does it show my commit as unverified?

**Example code:**

```
const privateKey = '[GENERATED PRIVATE KEY]';
const passphrase = '[RANDOM PASSPHRASE FROM EARLIER]';

const author = {
  name: '[NAME THAT MATCHES GITHUB]',
  email: '[EMAIL THAT MATCHES GITHUB]',
  date: new Date().toISOString(),
};

const commitPayload: CommitPayload = {
  message: commitMessage,
  author,
  committer: { ...author },
  tree: tree.data.sha,
  parents: [branch.data.object.sha],
};

const signature = await githubApiSignature.createSignature(
  commitPayload,
  privateKey,
  passphrase,
);

const result = await got(
  `[GITHUB API URL]/repos/[USERNAME]/[REPO_NAME]/git/commits`,
  {
    protocol: 'https:',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      ...commitPayload,
      signature,
    },
    json: true
  },
);
```

Comment: Can you verify the commit from the command line using `git verify-commit HASH`?

Comment: @bk2204 the output I get is `gpg: BAD signature from "Name <email>" [unknown]`, interestingly the RSA key is also much shorter (16 vs 40 chars) for this signature vs. one that was created successfully by a non-programmatically created commit using a different key a few days ago.

Comment: The RSA key does match the GPG key ID in my keys page in GitHub though.

Comment: The difference in lengths is the key ID versus the fingerprint and is not relevant.  I don't know _why_ your code is broken, but at least GitHub and Git agree that the signature is bad, so you know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a trailing `\n` in the commit message which was trimmed by the library I was using to generate the signature but not by me before POSTing to GitHub.

*Further information on how I debugged this, should it help anyone else further down the line:*

Originally I tried using the openpgp library directly following [the guide for creating and verifying detached signatures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp#create-and-verify-detached-signatures), and faced the same validity issue.

Knowing that the signature was verified locally I knew that I must be sending something to the GitHub API incorrectly. The [Git Commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/) provides some useful feedback in the `verification` block of the response:

```
verification: {
    verified: boolean
    reason: string
    signature: string
    payload: string
}
```

...as well as a little further information in the documentation page on what each of the reasons mean.

Further investigation of the payload (including simplifying all my values) led me to find that the message was at fault.

Comment: I'm in a similar boat, but don't have any trailing newlines. `git verify-commit <hash>` returns the `BAD signature from ...` message. What did you mean about "Knowing that the signature was verified locally", were you able to get the verify-commit command to return a success?